# Exclude NA values only and not entire rows in a lm in R?

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

If I have a dataset that looks like the following, looking at species richness of spiders in different habitats of a garden.

```
  'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ species_count: num  10 13 15 17 22 9
 $ habitat_type : Factor w/ 2 levels "wall","tree": 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ wall_height  : num  153 NA 160 NA 170 NA
 $ tree_diameter: num  NA 48 NA 52 NA 71
```

I want to create a lm with `species_count` as the dependent variable and `habitat_type`, `wall_height` and `tree_diameter` as the independent variables, however the NA's are tricky.

```
lm.1 <- lm(species_count ~ habitat_type + wall_height + tree_diameter,
           data = DF, na.action = na.exclude)
```

throws up the following error:

> Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

as `na.exclude` and `na.omit` delete the entire rows.

Using:

```
DF$wall_height <- na.exclude(DF$wall_height)
```

and

```
DF$tree_diameter <- na.exclude(DF$tree_diameter)
```

just repeats the values, giving `tree_diameter` values to `wall` and vice versa, like so:

```
DF[1,]
  ID species_count habitat_type wall_height tree_diameter
1  1            10         wall         153            48
```

Is there a way to omit `NA` values only whilst retaining the rest of the information within the row, or will I have to use separate linear models?

Thanks in advance for any help and hope that I've been clear enough in explaining the issue.

Comment: The least-squares algorithm works exclusively with numbers, thus NA are not possible. This is why R removes observations with NAs, which typically introduces bias. A typical workflow is to create multiple datasets with imputed values, perform the analysis of choice for each of the completed datasets and then combine the results using statistical tricks. Packages like `mice` ease that "multiple imputation" process considerably.

Comment: Do you only have 6 observations total, as you show here? Note that all cases with values for `wall_height` have NA for `tree_diameter`, and vice versa, so you have no complete cases at all for those two predictors. It seems that each of those is only defined for one of the two `habitat_type` values. Please edit your question to say more about what hypothesis you are trying to test, as this approach doesn't look like it's going to work.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your responses. EdM, as I have just created this dataset as an example to illustrate the issue with my main dataset, yes there are only 6 observations, 3 obs are walls and 3 obs are trees. `wall_height` doesn't apply to the `tree` obs and vice versa. Setting them to 0's or using replicates will skew the analysis? 

Michael M, I've been coming to the conclusion that I'd have to use separate datasets and combine. Thank you for the suggestion of `mice`, shall take a look!

Comment: Just seen the end of you comment, EdM. The hypothesis would be exploring what influences spider species richness in gardens; seeing if `habitat_type` has an influence, and then if the different variables have an influence, such as `wall_height` and `tree_diameter`. 

Was wondering if there was a way to combine them in one `lm` but looking like I'll have to do it separately.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that

> `wall_height` doesn't apply to the `tree` obs and vice versa.

So there is nothing to be gained by trying to analyze the data from `wall` and `tree` habitats together. In principle, you can compare the two habitats, and then evaluate how habitat-specific characteristics are associated with species numbers within a habitat.

In practice, you face a problem of very few observations. Usually you want about 10 cases per predictor that you are using in your model. You might be able to do an adequate comparison of the 2 habitats, but any results within a habitat, with only 3 observations each, will be highly suspect.

A couple of other thoughts. First, count data are often better analyzed with a different type of model, a Poisson generalized linear model. Second, the numbers of species are presumably represented by different numbers of individuals of each. There is probably some information to be gleaned from that, which should be explained in the ecology literature on species diversity.